# How to display string with break lines in a textarea

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I can simply set the value of a textarea like this:

```js
var foo='<div>Some html</div>\r\nSome html<br /><br />\r\n\r\n<div >Some html</div>\r\n</b>';
$('#my_textarea').val(foo);
```

and it shows the break lines properly.

In my case (working with Laravel) I'm trying to update my view using Jquery. I get the exact string as above as an Ajax response.

This string is saved in my database, and I am trying to display it with line breaks in the required textarea. This method `$('#my_textarea').val(foo);`, inside the Ajax success function, shows exactly the String as it is without line breaks (`\r\n`).

I tried also this:

```js
$('#my_textarea').val(foo.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
```

but also is not working.
What am I missing here?

PS: if I try this

```js
console.log(foo);
$('#my_textarea').val(foo);// not working 
$('#my_textarea').val(copied_foo);// working -- copied_foo:I copied the foo variable from the console
```

### update

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/get_sa_data", 
     data: {selected:sa_number},
     success: function(data) {
        var description=data.description;
        console.log(description);
        $('#sa_description >textarea').val(description);//break lines not working
        //$('#sa_description >textarea').val(copied_from_above_console.log);--> works
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `.html(foo)` instead of `.val(foo)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&npsb` instead of `\r` and `<br />` instead of `\n` . You are binding template, so just html tags should work.

Comment: Iam getting my data from my database, I have to displaying it as it is only with break lines.

Answer (score 0):

I made this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j747c25t/1/) for you, doing an Ajax call which return HTML.

Here is the javascript I made for my example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=html",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "HTML",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("textarea").html( data.replace(/<p>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, "&#10;") );
  }    
})
```

But in your case you should replace like that:

```
$("textarea").html( data.replace(/\r\n/g, "&#10;") );
```

The `"&#10;` is an [**HTML Entities<sup>Wikipédia</sup>**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for the Line Feed, there is also `&#13;` for the carriage return which you can use.

Comment: not working .. the main problem is that my script some how doesn't recognize the `\r\n` character

Comment: Can you show your ajax script ? OR better, a jsfiddle if it is possible ?

Comment: see update and please take the commented line on consideration.